# Plot multiple variables on one barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm working with this dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wholesale+customers

I want to plot a histogram with all the variables that have the amount spent (everything but region and channel). I'd like them to be plotted by channel, which has 2 levels. I got the following code from an example on a website, but put in my variables:

```
category=c(rep("Fresh",2),rep("Grocery",2),rep("Milk",2),rep("Frozen",2),
         rep("Detergents_Paper",2),rep("Delicassen",2))
condition=rep(c("Food Service", "Retail"))
value=abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data=data.frame(category,condition,value)

ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=category)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

This produces what I want, but it doesn't use my data. Here's the graph I get, but the values don't mean anything since they're basically random.

[image: Multivariate Histogram]

How do I get my data to plot like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By loading the tidyr package, the data can be reshaped to support the expected output.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
```

After reading in the data with the correct classes for the columns (factors for Channel and Region while the remaining six fields are numeric), check the data for correctness.

```r
df <- read.csv(file = url('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00292/Wholesale%20customers%20data.csv'), colClasses = c('factor','factor','numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric'))
```

```r
str(df)
```

```r
'data.frame':   440 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Channel         : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ Region          : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Fresh           : num  12669 7057 6353 13265 22615 ...
 $ Milk            : num  9656 9810 8808 1196 5410 ...
 $ Grocery         : num  7561 9568 7684 4221 7198 ...
 $ Frozen          : num  214 1762 2405 6404 3915 ...
 $ Detergents_Paper: num  2674 3293 3516 507 1777 ...
 $ Delicassen      : num  1338 1776 7844 1788 5185 ...
```

```r
head(df)
```

```r
  Channel Region Fresh Milk Grocery Frozen Detergents_Paper Delicassen
1       2      3 12669 9656    7561    214             2674       1338
2       2      3  7057 9810    9568   1762             3293       1776
3       2      3  6353 8808    7684   2405             3516       7844
4       1      3 13265 1196    4221   6404              507       1788
5       2      3 22615 5410    7198   3915             1777       5185
6       2      3  9413 8259    5126    666             1795       1451
```

The data appear to have imported correctly.

Next we use a combination of tidyr::gather and ggplot2::ggplot to produce the desired bar plot (not histogram).

```r
df %>%
  tidyr::gather(Type, Amount, -c(Channel, Region)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Type, y=Amount, fill=Channel, group=Channel)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

`tidyr::gather(Type, Amount, -c(Channel, Region))` will reshape the data set from this:

```r
  Channel Region Fresh Milk Grocery Frozen Detergents_Paper Delicassen
1       2      3 12669 9656    7561    214             2674       1338
2       2      3  7057 9810    9568   1762             3293       1776
3       2      3  6353 8808    7684   2405             3516       7844
4       1      3 13265 1196    4221   6404              507       1788
5       2      3 22615 5410    7198   3915             1777       5185
6       2      3  9413 8259    5126    666             1795       1451
```

To a "longer" data set which now has the product type as rows:

```r
  Channel Region  Type Amount
1       2      3 Fresh  12669
2       2      3 Fresh   7057
3       2      3 Fresh   6353
4       1      3 Fresh  13265
5       2      3 Fresh  22615
6       2      3 Fresh   9413
```

This prepares the data to be plotted using ggplot2::ggplot where the x input can be mapped to the new Type variable and the y variable to Amount.
Be sure to use `Group=Channel` and `position=position_dodge()` so that ggplot will know that you want the bars side-by-side.